# Jquery Script won't click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, enter

I use this script to trigger button click upon `keyup` event inside the textbox, but it fails to do what is required:

```
 $("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
 if(event.keyCode == 13){
     $("#id_of_button").click();
 }
});
```

Comment: what do you want it to do?

Comment: `I use JQuery 1.1.1`. Maybe you need to upgrade the version. This is from stone age.

Comment: Your code works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/5n7yb1yy/ . Share your complete code or upgrade the jquery version

Comment: @George in your example, it is submitted, you are wrong in the example but you are right in the theory.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Technically your example uses a newer version of jQuery but changing it to the correct version still shows the expected behavior.

Comment: So what is not working exactly? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @MikeC jQuery 1.1.1 doesn't exists in jsfiddle (since years ago)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude My mistake, I read that as `1.11.1`. Too many damn 1's haha.

Comment: [Here is an example of your code with the correct version.](https://jsfiddle.net/a2sbst1o/1/) It works perfectly.

Comment: @MikeC I know that works since '90s LOL, but in my comment I said another thing: **_Share your complete code_ or upgrade the jquery version**

Comment: The problem is that you are invoking the click event but there is no click event binding on that element. So you need to declare the binding before you invoke it.

Comment: I'd like another solytion because I don't know JQuery, I was just using this script, how about a script to run this? I need (and that was my complete code btw) I'd like it when enter is pressed, it runs THIS script:

Comment: document.location.href = 'http://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' + escape(document.getElementById('search-box').value)

Answer (score 0):

try: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/60u94fty/

```
<input type="text" id="id_of_textbox" />
<button id="id_of_button">Click Button</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("id_of_button").onclick = function() {clickFunction()};

function clickFunction() {alert("hello");}

$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
   if(event.keyCode === 13){
      $("#id_of_button").click();
   }
});

</script>
```

Comment: I read and create my jsfiddle.If another resolved while i do my solution, is not my problem!

Comment: If it makes you happy, so I delete and be happy!

Comment: No, don't remove it. Edit the post with a minimal change to allows me to remove downvote.